# How to list users with role names in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I have default project template of ASP.NET MVC 5 web site and I am trying to list all users with role names (not IDs).

The query is:

```
db.Users.Include(u => u.Roles).ToList()
```

Then I want to print the role names with something like:

```
@string.Join(", ", user.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId))
```

The problem is that I can reach only `RoleId`, not Role class where `Name` and other properties are stored.

I could run another select to get all roles and then use that as a lookup. Or write a join in the query directly? I am not sure how because I do not have access to the table with `IdentityUserRole` entities that are binding users and roles together.

The root of the problem seems to be the fact that is Roles collection of `IdentityUserRole` (not `Role`) which contains only `RoleId` and `UserId`.

```
public class IdentityUserRole<TKey> {
    public virtual TKey RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual TKey UserId { get; set; }
}
```

I thought that if one want to do N-to-N relationship in EF they should put directly collection of `Roles` and then override `OnModelCreating` and specify the relationships. This approach seems to complicate browsing the objects from one to another.

Why they decided to include `IdentityUserRole` as extra entity? To be able to add extra data to the relationships? At cost of not being able to navigate from users to roles?

Comment: you can easily navigate from user to roles, the join table is there because there is a many to many relationship. I dont think the Identity team just make a rubbish system for fun....

Comment: @No1_Melman Could you please include an example of the query (maybe as an answer)? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah give me a minute

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The way I do it is:

```
using (var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationContext()))
{
    var rolesForUser = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(userId);

   // rolesForUser now has a list role classes.
}
```

The identity team made two managers: `RoleManager` for sorting out roles (not user roles though) and `UserManager` basically for everything authentication wise. There is also a `SignInManager` as well but not needed.

So `UserManager` finds users, creates users, deletes users, sends emails .... the list goes on.

So my `Action` could look like this:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetRolesForUser(string userId)
    {
        using (
            var userManager =
                new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
        {
            var rolesForUser = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(userId);

            return this.View(rolesForUser);
        }
    }
```

To execute raw SQL then you can do something like this:

Create the class that Entity Framework can map to, based on the output of your query:

```
public class UserWithRole
{
    public string UserName {get;set;} // You can alias the SQL output to give these better names
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var sql = @"
                SELECT AspNetUsers.UserName, AspNetRoles.Name 
                FROM AspNetUsers 
                LEFT JOIN AspNetUserRoles ON  AspNetUserRoles.UserId = AspNetUsers.Id 
                LEFT JOIN AspNetRoles ON AspNetRoles.Id = AspNetUserRoles.RoleId
                WHERE AspNetUsers.Id = @Id";
    var idParam = new SqlParameter("Id", theUserId);

    var result = context.Database.ExecuteQuery<UserWithRole>(sql, idParam);
}
```

Pretty simple!

If you alias your SQL return columns:

```
SELECT AspNetUSers.UserName, AspNetRoles.Name As RoleName
```

Then your DTO class can look like this:

```
public class UserWithRole
{
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public string RoleName {get;set;}
}
```

Which is obviously a lot cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but where did you get the `UserRoles` DbSet? In default `IdentityDbContext` there are only `Roles` and `Users`  DbSets which makes such join not possible in my eyes.

Comment: Yeah I just spun up a project to have a look, but found there was nothing, which is bizarre, because in all of my projects I do this, but I think I have found the reason!

Comment: I see, so there is no "nice" way how to make a single query. I have to list users and then query roles for every user separately, right? I am not sure why it is so "complicated".

Comment: Yes you would do it separately. However, from the stand point of speed, it would not bode well to go to the database and retrieve all the users with their associated roles. In the web page, you would want to make an AJAX request each time the user requested them.

Comment: If you post the SQL to achieve what you want then I can show you how to execute it from EF! @NightElfik

Comment: Thank for your answer. I ended up using `Dictionary` as a lookup table from `RoleId` to `RoleName`. The SQL that I was looking for was something like this (but with every user having IEnumerable<IdentityRole>): `SELECT AspNetUsers.UserName, AspNetRoles.Name FROM AspNetUsers LEFT JOIN AspNetUserRoles ON AspNetUserRoles.UserId = AspNetUsers.Id LEFT JOIN AspNetRoles ON AspNetRoles.Id = AspNetUserRoles.RoleId`

Comment: @NightElfik I updated my answer to execute the database SQL from EF

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it with MVC 5, Identity 2.0 and a custom user and role describe by [John Atten](http://johnatten.com/2014/06/22/asp-net-identity-2-0-customizing-users-and-roles/)

**In controller**

```
public virtual ActionResult ListUser()
    {            
        var users = UserManager.Users;
        var roles = new List<string>();
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            string str = "";
            foreach (var role in UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id))
            {
                str = (str == "") ? role.ToString() : str + " - " + role.ToString();
            }
            roles.Add(str);
        }
        var model = new ListUserViewModel() {
            users = users.ToList(),
            roles = roles.ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

**In ViewModel**

```
public class ListUserViewModel
{
    public IList<YourAppNamespace.Models.ApplicationUser> users { get; set; }
    public IList<string> roles { get; set; }
}
```

**And in my View**

```
@{
    int i = 0;
}
@foreach (var item in Model.users)
{   
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>  item.Name)
    [... Use all the properties and formating you want ... and ] 
    @Model.roles[i]
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Callum Linington for his answer. Just Try to make it little bit clear for beginners like me.
Here is steps to get a list of users with their roles.

1- Create a view model called "UsersWithRoles" with some properties as shown below :

[image]

2- Create a controller called "RolesController", and then add following piece of code in it.

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var sql = @"
            SELECT AspNetUsers.UserName, AspNetRoles.Name As Role
            FROM AspNetUsers 
            LEFT JOIN AspNetUserRoles ON  AspNetUserRoles.UserId = AspNetUsers.Id 
            LEFT JOIN AspNetRoles ON AspNetRoles.Id = AspNetUserRoles.RoleId";
            //WHERE AspNetUsers.Id = @Id";
            //var idParam = new SqlParameter("Id", theUserId);

            var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<UserWithRoles>(sql).ToList();
            return View(result);
        }

    }
```

and here is what the RolesController should look like :

[image]

3- Add Index page to Roles folder, and add the following code in it.

```html
@model IEnumerable<MVC_Auth.ViewModels.UserWithRoles>
<div class="row">
    <h4>Users</h4>
    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-striped table-bordered">
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        @foreach (var user in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@user.UserName</td>
                <td>@user.Role</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the result

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think its bad technique to execute dynamic SQL from your C# application. Below is my method:

Model:

```
  public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
  {
    public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
    public ApplicationRole(string name) : base(name) { }
    public string Description { get; set; }

  }
```

Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

//Example for Details.
if (id == null)
  {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }
  var role = await RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
  // Get the list of Users in this Role
  var users = new List<ApplicationUser>();

  // Get the list of Users in this Role
  foreach (var user in UserManager.Users.ToList())
  {
    if (await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id, role.Name))
    {
      users.Add(user);
    }
  }

  ViewBag.Users = users;
  ViewBag.UserCount = users.Count();
  return View(role);
```

View (using ApplicationRole)

```
    <div>
        <h4>Roles.</h4>
        <hr />
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <h4>List of users in this role</h4>
    @if (ViewBag.UserCount == 0)
{
        <hr />
        <p>No users found in this role.</p>
}
    <table class="table">
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Users)
    {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.UserName
                </td>
            </tr>
    }
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;

            var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var Users = db.Users.Include(u => u.Roles);

            foreach (var item in Users)
            {
                string UserName = item.UserName;
                string Roles = string.Join(",", item.Roles.Select(r=>r.RoleId).ToList());
            }
```