# ASP.Net MVC5: Efficient method to get list of user in specific role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29892521/1080355), I implemented below code to get list of `ApplicationUsers` in a specific role.

I need to mention that ApplicationUser is an extention of IdentityUser. I want to know are there any better methods for this?

```
ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var store = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<ApplicationUser>(dbContext);
var manager = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store); 
List<ApplicationUser>  users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
foreach (ApplicationUser user in manager.Users.ToList())
{
    if (manager.IsInRole(user.Id,"Admin")){
        users.Add(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest below method:

```
public static bool isInRole(IPrincipal User, string roleName, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
{
    try
    {
        var store = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<ApplicationUser>(dbContext);
        var manager = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
        return manager.IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), roleName);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query like this

```
ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var role = context.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Admin");
var usersInRole = context.Users.Where(m => m.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId != role.Id));
```

I am not sure if this is the optimal way, but does less queries to database than your code.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't better way.

But assuming you are using that in your controller you could create a BaseController where every other controller is derived from.

Inside that BaseController you can instantiate the ApplicationManager and create a method that optionally receives an ID (UserId) and returns a bool.

Which you could call in your controller like this:

```
if(HasRole("Owner")) {} // CurrentUser
if(HasRole(Id, "Owner")) {} // Specific User
```

There are other ways, but that's a developer choise.

**Note**

Keep in mind that if you choose to statically instantiate the ApplicationManager, it will run only once which may do things that you don't want, like adding a user to a specific role and that ApplicationManager not showing the new role unless it is created again.